# How to construct a new distributions object from a tensor in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want compute the KL divergence between Normal distribution and tensor output by CNN.

[KL function](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/contrib.distributions/kullback_leibler_divergence)

the argu must be instance of distributions.Distribution.
So, I don't know how to constucting an instance of Distribution from my tensor which is output of CNN.

Comment: How would you do it in numpy / python?

Comment: In the layer of your network, you can use `softmax` to make it output a probability distribution but it is a instance of `distributions.Distribution`.

Comment: @fabrizioM Yes, using tensorflow 1.0 in python

Comment: @Fake but the output of softmax is not a instance of distributions.Distribution